# Бесконечная прокрутка графика в пределах одной области графика

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Я использую c #.

Необходимо реализовать бесконечную прокрутку графика в Chart c #. Я имею в виду, что если я удерживаю правую кнопку мыши и перемещаю курсор, график перемещается, и если какая-то часть выходит за пределы области, то она рисуется с другой стороны. Область, в которой строится график, от -180 до 180. Получается эффект прокрутки карты. Если вы не можете сделать это в диаграмме, скажите мне, где вы можете это сделать

Comment: вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Вопрос в том как это реализовать , примеров не могу найти , желательно такое реализовать именно в компоненте chart , winform